# How to specify which server should a Windows 10 PC get its updates from

Tags: windows-10-preview, homegroup

Windows 10 latest build has an option to get updates from other places than Microsoft's servers, like other computers on the network. Is there any registery key or group policy settings to specify the server's IP address to get updates from? by server, i mean another computer running Windows 10 that is on a different subnet.

Comment: You accomplish this exactly how you accomplished this in previous Windows.

Comment: I found [this guide](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/450131-point-windows-7-regedit-to-wsus-server) but those keys aren't present in Windows 10 or even 8.1. do you know how to do it?

Comment: You linked to a a discussion on Windows 7.  I promise you those steps still work.

Comment: Okay, another question, using this [method](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-8/group-policy-settings-wsus) via group policy in Windows 10, will it work? maybe older versions of Windows have to be on the same domain or workgroup but does Windows 10 need them too or will it recognize the IP address of the WSUS regardless of its domain or other things?

Comment: Windows 10 RTM will support the Insider Preview does not.  Windows 10 has to support it, and I know for a fact it will, for the simple fact Enterprise will use WSUS if they use Windows 10.

Comment: Yes you're right, but Microsoft added this feature to Windows 10 pro to let home users use this feature too without having an enterprise or server edition of Windows. so i guess every Windows 10 pro will be a WSUS for others, am i right?

Comment: All retail versions of Windows have support for it.